# SimCom SIM7000E sends multiple RDY unsolicited result codes

Tags: arduino, hardware, at-command

I have been working with an Arduino and a SIM7000E NB-IoT HAT for a little while now. The Arduino is communicating via SoftwareSerial with the SIM modem. They are connected via simple jumper wires. For testing purposes, my application only forwards messages between the SoftwareSerial port and the serial monitor.

The problem I am facing is that I repeatedly get the unsolicited result code `RDY` followed by `+CFUN: 1`, `+CPIN: READY` and `SMS Ready`. As I understand it ([and as stated here](https://momoiot.co.kr/catm-at/cmd/unsolicited-codes/)), the result code `RDY` should only be sent by the modem after the power on procedure is finished. I get this message so often that it inhibits other communication with the modem as I cannot send commands while receiving this unsolicited message.

Can anyone tell me why this could be happening?
Is my modem faulty and rebooting, resulting in the repeated power on message? Or could it be something else?